# Лучший способ ограничить количество знаков в тексте

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста способ сократить количество знаков в тексте если например он привышает 20 знаков.
Желательно чтобы было как можно меньше кода.

Мой способ (который недостаточно эффективен)

```css
.box {
width: 600 px;
height: 700px;
color: white;
background-color: #000;
}

.cuttedText {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p class="cuttedText">proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему ваш способ не эффективен?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko потому что не учитывает длину в 20 символов?

Comment: @teran это вопрос подбора адекватной ширины элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать 'monospace' шрифт, у которого ширина всех символов одинаковая. Тогда можно будет посчитать ширину и указать его в пикселях.

> Считаем ширину символа:

Куда-нибудь добавляется тестовый span, внутри которого 100 символов, чтобы увеличить точность измерений. В консоли записываем реальную ширину элемента, разделенную на 100, получаем ширину букв с точностью до ,00

```js
console.log( document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth / 100 );
```

```css
*{font-size: 16px; font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco;}
```

```html
<span id="test">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
```

Сделал более точный калькулятор → https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/x5qk608a/ , быстрее можно будет считать)

Когда уже имеется ширина для конкретного шрифта и font-size, умножаем его на 20, и о чудо!)

```css
*{font-size: 16px; font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco;}

.cuttedText {
  display: block;
  width: 192.8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="cuttedText">proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna</p>

<p class="cuttedText">С точки зрения банальной эрудиции, каждый индивидуум...</p>

<p class="cuttedText">А на Чебурашкины именины, испекли мы каравай...</p>
```

Можете поискать и другие шрифты `monospace` ...

P.s. если нужно именно 20 символов оставить, умножаем на 23, вместо 20.

---

А если имеется текст разных размеров и везде нужно порезать 20 символов, тут только JS... этот вариант сработает для всех таких элементов, не только для первого (учитывает и пробелы):

```js
(function(){
  var cut = document.getElementsByClassName('cuttedText');
  for( var i = 0; i < cut.length; i++ ){
    cut[i].innerText = cut[i].innerText.slice(0,20) + '...';
  }
})();
```

```css
.font2 {font-size: 24px;}
.font3 {font-size: 36px; font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva';}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p class="cuttedText">абвгд еёжзи йк лмно прстуф хцчшщ ъыь эюя</p>
  <p class="cuttedText font2">абвгд еёжзи йк лмно прстуф хцчшщ ъыь эюя</p>
  <p class="cuttedText font3">абвгд еёжзи йк лмно прстуф хцчшщ ъыь эюя</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("innerHTML").length > 20){
      let val = $(this).prop("innerHTML");
      $(this).attr("title", val);
      $(this).prop("innerHTML", val.substr(0,20) + "...")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>восьмидесятичетырёхлетний</p>
<p>тысячадевятьсотвосьмидесятидевятимиллиметровый</p>
<p>словотетрагидропиранилциклопентилтетрагидропиридопиридиновые </p>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("value", val);` - это для какого элемента?

Comment: 1) я исправил 2) для текущего "p" по циклу

Comment: А `input` тогда зачем?) И 20 уже тогда сделайте

Comment: @br3t не правильно вопрос понял сначала. На 20-ти плохо заметно )))) Я думаю автор поймет что менять

Answer (score 0):

коли у вас метка jquery стоит

```js
$(function(){
  var txt = $(".cuttedText").text().trim();
  if(txt.length > 20){
     $(".cuttedText").text( txt.substring(0,20) + '...');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p class="cuttedText">proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna</p>
</div>
```